# Rails 3.1: Trying to update ActiveRecord: NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fdfb82aca98>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to update an ActiveRecord, which seems like it SHOULD be easy enough. Methods I've tried in my

**Controller (metadata_controller.rb)**:

```
  def update_metadata_type
    @metadata_type = MetadataType.find(params[:id])
    if @metadata_type.update_attributes(params)
      render :template => 'metadata/show_metadata_type'
    else
      # return error template
    end
  end

  def update_metadata_type
    if MetadataType.update(1, { :name => params[:name] })
      render :template => 'metadata/show_metadata_type'
    else
      # return error template
    end
  end

  def update_metadata_type
    @metadata_type = MetadataType.find(params[:id])
    @metadata_type.name = params[:name]
    @metadata_type.save

    render :template => 'metadata/show_metadata_type'
  end
```

**Model (metadata_type.rb):**

```
class MetadataType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :metadata_type_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :attributes, :through => :metadata_type_attributes, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :name, :attribute_type_id

  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
end
```

**Different model with same problem (attribute_type.rb):**

```
class AttributeType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attributes

  attr_accessible :data_type

  validates :data_type, :uniqueness => true
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
  match '/metadata_type/:id' => 'metadata#update_metadata_type', :via => [:put], :as => 'update_metadata_type'
```

Each time I'm sending the data using [RESTClient](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/), with the appropriate headers to send json, with the following data in a PUT command:

```
{
    "name" : "NewName"
}
```

I've also used binding.pry in the controller to make sure @metadata_type is found (and not nil) and it always looks right:

```
[1] pry(#<MetadataController>)> @metadata_type = MetadataType.find(params[:id])
=> #<MetadataType id: 1, name: "Category", created_at: "2011-11-15 16:02:53", updated_at: "2011-11-15 16:02:53">
```

Params also looks right:

```
[7] pry(#<MetadataController>)> params
=> {"name"=>"NewName",
 "controller"=>"metadata",
 "action"=>"update_metadata_type",
 "id"=>"1",
 "metadatum"=>{"name"=>"NewName"}}
```

But for some reason, no matter how I try and save, I get the same error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `keys' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fdfb7637fd8>):
  app/controllers/metadata_controller.rb:50:in `update_metadata_type'
```

Any idea on what's causing this? All help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a little late to the party but you can't define an association with the name `attributes` as it ends up overriding the built in `attributes` accessor method defined and used by ActiveRecord itself.

Well hopefully this helps anyone else who happens to come across this obscure error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these lines:

```
has_many :metadata_type_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :attributes, :through => :metadata_type_attributes, :dependent => :destroy
```

I'm a little confused as to what exactly you're trying to do, but I suspect you mean:

```
has_many :attributes, :class_name => "MetadataTypeAttributes", :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be it. I tried your edit and now get this error instead: `NameError: uninitialized constant MetadataType::MetadataTypeAttributes from /Users/dsavage/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:1341:in compute_type'`. I've also edited above and added a different model I'm trying to do the same thing with that's having the same problem.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the set up of your Models. Why does Metadata have many Attributes and MetadataTypeAttributes. Does both have models? Post the associated models and some explanation of your model schema if possible.